# Partial Differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: calculus

How can I obtain the partial derivative respect to the variable $y$ of

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\int _{ zx-5y }^{ z+2{ y }^{ 2 } }{ g\left( t \right)  } \,dt$$

I cannot find how to apply the derivative under the integral sign.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g(t)$ does not depend on $y$ we don't differentiate under the integral.  Rather, we simply use the chain rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\int_{zx-5y}^{z+2y^2}g(t)\,dt&=g(z+2y^2)\frac{\partial (z+2y^2)}{\partial y}-g(zx-5y)\frac{\partial (zx-5y)}{\partial y}\\\\
&=4yg(z+2y^2)+5g(zx-5y)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Victor, ... just looking for your feedback.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark